# How do I debug an Akka-Stream pipeline?

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe, akka-stream

I am trying to build a processing pipeline for a log file where log lines look like

```
2005-05-06 14:58:57 1 45.23.4.218 304 TCP_HIT 542 1109 GET http sports.espn.go.com /crossdomain.xml - - DIRECT 199.181.132.141 text/xml "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)" PROXIED Sports/Recreation/Hobbies - 192.16.170.44 SG-HTTP-Service - none -
```

For this specific log file I have around **193705** log lines that I want to process.

```
Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:bluecoat_proxy_big harit$ wc -l Demo_log_004.log 
  195765 Demo_log_004.log
Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:bluecoat_proxy_big harit$ grep -E "GET|POST|CONNECT" Demo_log_004.log | wc -l
  192197
Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:bluecoat_proxy_big harit$ wc -l Demo_log_004.log 
  195765 Demo_log_004.log
Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:bluecoat_proxy_big harit$ grep -v "^#" Demo_log_004.log | wc -l
  193705
Harits-MacBook-Pro-2:bluecoat_proxy_big harit$
```

I created a flow graph that initially looked like

```
  source ~> byteStringToString ~> filterComments ~> splitLogLine ~> broadcast ~> transformEvent ~> sinkEvents
                                                                    broadcast ~> obfuscateIpAddress ~> sinkAssets
```

But then I realized that I was getting lot less in Sink

```
$ java -cp processor/target/lib:processor/target/processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.learner.processor.LogFile | tee out.log

$ wc -l out.log 
   15070 out.log
```

So I made my graph linear to make sure if all lines pass through pipes. My current code looks like

```
import java.io.File

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.io.Implicits.AddSynchronousFileSource
import akka.stream.scaladsl.FlowGraph.Builder
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.learner.messages.BlueCoatEvent
import com.learner.processor.Flows.byteStringToString
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.stringHash

object LogFile {
  val maxBytesPerLine = 1500
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")

  def apply(file: File) = new LogFile(file)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    LogFile(new File("/Users/harit/Downloads/bluecoat_proxy_big/Demo_log_004.log")).processGraph()
  }
}

class LogFile(file: File)(implicit val system: ActorSystem) {
  Predef.assert(file.exists(), "log file must exists")

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass))

  val source: Source[ByteString, Future[Long]] = Source.synchronousFile(file)


  def processGraph() = {
    val sinkEvents = Sink.foreach(println)
    val sinkAssets = Sink.ignore

    val filterComments = Flow[String].filter(!_.startsWith("#"))
    val splitLogLine = Flow[String].map(_.split("\\s") toList)
    val transformEvent = Flow[List[String]].map(tokens => BlueCoatEvent(tokens))
    val obfuscateIpAddress = Flow[List[String]].map(tokens => Map[String, String](tokens(3) -> stringHash(tokens(3)).toString))


    FlowGraph.closed() { implicit builder: Builder[Unit] =>
      import FlowGraph.Implicits._

      source ~> byteStringToString ~> sinkEvents
    }.run()

  }
}
```

and

```
  val byteStringToString: Flow[ByteString, String, Unit] = Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), maximumFrameLength = LogFile.maxBytesPerLine, allowTruncation = true))
    .map(_.utf8String)
```

When I ran my program again, it is again generating lines somewhere near to above number (no exactly same)

I am confused and wanted get some help here

1. The stream does not fail or throw exceptions, but still generates
   lot less output lines, How do I debug this?
2. The `maximumFrameLength` is **1500**, however the log lines can be greater than that (more characters). Can that be an issue? How do I resolve such a case then?
3. How do I confirm? As per my code, I do not get back the
   `Materializer` when I call `run()`, so I am unable to shutdown the
   `ActorSystem`, what am I missing there?

**UPDATE**

I just found out that it halts for line which has `2564 chars(bytes)`

```
15070 2005-05-06 14:58:57 42 45.23.4.218 200 TCP_NC_MISS 903 1098 GET http sports.espn.go.com /nba/xml/upcomingTV ?sport=nba - DIRECT sports.espn.go.com text/html;%20charset=iso-       8859-1 "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)" PROXIED Sports/Recreation/Hobbies - 192.16.170.44 SG-HTTP-Service - none -
15071 2005-05-06 14:58:57 306 45.23.4.218 200 TCP_MISS 16641 2140 GET http m3.doubleclick.net /872526/match2fb_728x90v2.swf ?clickTag=http%253A//ad.doubleclick.net/click%25253Bh%       253Dv3%257C3270%257Cf%257C6e%257C%25252a%257Ct%25253B14910813%25253B0-0%25253B0%25253B11166676%25253B3454-728%257C90%25253B9369149%257C9387045%257C1%25253B%25253B%25257Essc       s%25253D%25253fhttp%253A//log.go.com/log%253Fsrvc%25253dsz%252526guid%25253d5504B8AD-0FC2-4475-9203-4CE6D2125953%252526drop%25253d0%252526addata%25253d0%253A63%253A188329%2       53A65%252526a%25253d1%252526goto%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww.levitra.com/match/levitra_promotions/match/get/forms.jsp%25253Frotation%25253D11166676%252526banner%2525       3D14910813&clickTag1=http%253A//log.go.com/log%253Fsrvc%25253dsz%252526guid%25253d5504B8AD-0FC2-4475-9203-4CE6D2125953%252526drop%25253d0%252526addata%25253d0%253A63%253A18       8329%253A65%252526a%25253d1%252526goto%25253dhttp%253A//ad.doubleclick.net/click%25253Bh%253Dv3%257C3270%257Cf%257C6e%257C%25252a%257Ct%25253B14910813%25253B0-0%25253B0%252       53B11166676%25253B3454-728%257C90%25253B9369149%257C9387045%257C1%25253B%25253B%25257Esscs%25253D%25253fhttp%253A//log.go.com/log%253Fsrvc%25253dsz%252526guid%25253d5504B8A       D-0FC2-4475-9203-4CE6D2125953%252526drop%25253d0%252526addata%25253d0%253A63%253A188329%253A65%252526a%25253d1%252526goto%25253dhttp%25253a%25252f%25252fwww.levitra.com/mat       ch/levitra_promotions/match/get/forms.jsp%25253Frotation%25253D11166676%252526banner%25253D14910813&clickTag2=http%253A//log.go.com/log%253Fsrvc%25253dsz%252526guid%25253d5       504B8AD-0FC2-4475-9203-4CE6D2125953%252526drop%25253d0%252526addata%25253d0%253A63%253A188329%253A65%252526a%25253d1%252526goto%25253dhttp%253A//ad.doubleclick.net/click%25       253Bh%253Dv3%257C3270%257Cf%257C6e%257C%25252a%257Ct%25253B14910813%25253B0-0%25253B0%25253B11166676%25253B3454-728%257C90%25253B9369149%257C9387045%257C1%25253B%25253B%252       57Esscs%25253D%25253fhttp%253A//log.go.com/log%253Fsrvc%25253dsz%252526guid%25253d5504B8AD-0FC2-4475-9203-4CE6D2125953%252526drop%25253d0%252526addata%25253d0%253A63%253A18       8329%253A65%252526a%25253d1%252526goto%25253dhttp%253A//www.levitra.com/consumer/about_levitra/levitra_side_effects.htm%253Frotation%253D11166676%2526banner%253D14910813&cl       ickTag3=&clickTag4=&clickTag5= - DIRECT m3.doubleclick.net application/x-shockwave-flash "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)" PROXIED Web       %20Advertisements - 192.16.170.44 SG-HTTP-Service - none -
```

and

```
$ wc -l out.log 
   15070 out.log
```

so it halts for `line 15071` which is `2564 bytes`.

But why is it not throwing exception? How do I handle this?

Comment: For a start I would await on the future returned by the sink until it completes, before terminating the application. See here: https://github.com/softwaremill/streams-tests/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/streams/TransferTransformFile.scala on how to materialize the stream to the sink's value (you need to pass it to the graph builder)

Comment: Ideally, I would not terminate the application since it is expected to run forever and process logfiles, but as I see `IntersperseStage` is supposed to send `element`s separated by `\n`, right?

Comment: `IntersperseStage` - yes, it inserts the given element between each two elements. Though I'm not sure it has anything to do with your problems:)

Comment: No no, it's not ;-). I am learning both `Scala` and `Akka` so reading code to make sure I understand it

Comment: There is a `recover` option that might be useful to the output of `processGraph()`. Here is a SO referencing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833742/akka-stream-graph-recover-issue, and the actual docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-error.html